# Regex with Day One 2 JSON Export

Tags: php, json, regex

I'm writing a blog with Laravel 5.3 and Day One 2 app (iOS and macos) as a backend solution. Oh, and I start a world tour in two weeks, I'm a lil'bit in a hurry :/

I export my Day One 2 entries with the JSON export option, who generate a zip file which is stored on a Dropbox account. I have no  problem to get the file from Dropbox, open the ZIP and get the JSON output. But...

The fact is I need an regex-guru to deal with the entrie text field, specially to find/insert image or gallery.

Here is an example of JSON output (text entry looks like Markdown syntax I guess) :

```
{
"metadata" : {
  "version" : "1.0"
},
"entries" : [
{
  "tags" : [
    "discover",
    "explore"
  ],
  "uuid" : "4E032198058E43E5B740000C307F3678",
  "text" : "
  # The Heading Test\n
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat...\n
  ![](dayone-moment:\/\/6BC7C34BF2C34AFFB295014ECC818B15)\n
  ![](dayone-moment:\/\/E69CE22AC6AD4F38A18705499C7016ED)\n
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat...\n
  \n
  ![](dayone-moment:\/\/74A52813A7C74897B210BCE7EFE1EB86)",
  "photos" : [
    {
      "fnumber" : "(null)",
      "orderInEntry" : 2,
      "width" : 1690,
      "type" : "jpeg",
      "identifier" : "74A52813A7C74897B210BCE7EFE1EB86",
      "height" : 1169,
      "md5" : "2870b8aea3e95bdd06f9cec2d7c45a61",
      "focalLength" : "(null)"
    },
    {
      "fnumber" : "(null)",
      "orderInEntry" : 1,
      "width" : 2048,
      "type" : "jpeg",
      "identifier" : "E69CE22AC6AD4F38A18705499C7016ED",
      "height" : 1184,
      "md5" : "8e160d66157e3292bd1de3ced2a6c683",
      "focalLength" : "(null)"
    },
    {
      "cameraMake" : "Canon",
      "fnumber" : "8",
      "orderInEntry" : 0,
      "width" : 2100,
      "cameraModel" : "Canon EOS 1100D",
      "type" : "jpeg",
      "identifier" : "6BC7C34BF2C34AFFB295014ECC818B15",
      "date" : "2014-03-20T18:18:05Z",
      "exposureBiasValue" : 0,
      "height" : 1371,
      "lensModel" : "EF-S18-55mm f\/3.5-5.6 IS II",
      "md5" : "9a762493484888a70e02858887654dce",
      "focalLength" : "30"
    }
  ],
  "creationDate" : "2016-10-06T09:14:50Z",
  "duration" : 0,
  "starred" : true,
  "timeZone" : "Indian\/Reunion"
}
]}
```

As you see, the `![](dayone-moment:\/\/photo_identifier)` 'tag' contain a photo identifier, not the picture name which is not really simple. The name of jpg file is the MD5 field (yep, strange).

So the idea is:

- remplace `![](dayone-moment:\/\/photo_identifier_field)` by a `<img
  src="photo_md5_field">`
- and if I have two or more  side-by-side (or just after a \n), add a gallery like this:

`<section>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div><img src="photo1_md5_field"></div>
        <div><img src="photo2_md5_field"></div>
        <div>...<div>
    </div>
</section>`

Oh, one more thing... how to extract the first line (used as Title) and the second one (used as Subtitle)?

I know, it's a big request but I'm totally lost in translation with Regex :/

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you please add the result you want to achieve?

Comment: hi, post was edited with corrected code gallery syntax :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this code, it will do the work:

```
$json = json_decode($text, true);

foreach ($json['entries'] as $key => $item) {
    foreach($item['photos'] as $photo) {
        $json['entries'][$key]['text'] = preg_replace('/(\!\[\]\(dayone-moment:[\/\\\]*('.$photo['identifier'].')\).*)/', '<img src="'.$photo['md5'].'" />', $json['entries'][$key]['text']);
    }
    $json['entries'][$key]['text'] = preg_replace('/(\<img\ src=\"[a-zA-Z0-9]*\" \/\>)/', '<div>$1</div>', $json['entries'][$key]['text']);
    $json['entries'][$key]['text'] = preg_replace('/((<div\><img\ src=\"[a-zA-Z0-9]*\" \/\><\/div\>(\\n*\s*)?){2,})/', '<section><div id="wrapper">$1</div></section>', $json['entries'][$key]['text']);
}

$json = json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Works well but $2 return (obviously) the `photo_identifier`. As said above, I need to grab the appropriate value (md5 field) in the json file, wich seems a pain in the a** (thanks Day One for your complicated idea) :/

Comment: Hi, I'll give a try now, MD5 is correctly show for each photos. Is amazing :) But with the third preg_replace, each img tag is between a section tag. Looks fine if I replace `'/((<div\><img\ src=\"[a-zA-Z0-9]*\" \/\><\/div\>\\n?)+)/'` by `/((<div\><img\ src=\"[a-zA-Z0-9]*\" \/\><\/div\>\\n?)+)/` (* instead ?)

Comment: Ow, your latest update doesn't work: each img tags are in a div only, no section anymore :/

Comment: It works locally on my pc. May be it doesn't work because of the new lines in the `"text" : "`. Can you post the exact json that you are passing to json_decode?

Comment: You're right, I checked the text entrie: I have a double \n after each dayone-moment... Here's a copy of json text `"text" => """
        # title\n
        subtitle.\n
        \n
        ![](dayone-moment://6BC7C34BF2C34AFFB295014ECC818B15)\n
        \n
        text here.\n
        \n
        text here.\n
        \n
        ![](dayone-moment://E69CE22AC6AD4F38A18705499C7016ED)\n
        \n
        ![](dayone-moment://74A52813A7C74897B210BCE7EFE1EB86)
        """`

Comment: Ok :) check now

Comment: You know what? You R-O-C-K ! Works perfectly as expected. (\s, well see)

Comment: I'm glad I helped you!